# WSO2 BPS - Arrival order of messages

Tags: wso2, bpel, business-process

I already posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10348635/1360773), and I finally found the source of the problem myself. But the issue remains unresolved.

Arriving messages are stored in a queue until a matching activity is found. But if the activities are not activated in the same order as the messages arrived, the process will block.

I modelled a diagram which is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yacTm.png), the corresponding BPEL package can be downloaded from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21678026/testCase.zip).
The first process remains blocked on Receive2 whereas the second completes.

I'm testing on the BPS version 2.1.2

When multiple processes are communicating with each other, I do not always know if a message will arrive before or after another one. I think this should be possible, I see no reason why not: the messages are present in the H2 database, so a suitable query sould be able to return them.

Thanks in advance for your help.